# I'm trying to make an insert in the following code using images, I get the following error

Tags: php, sql-server, navicat

I'm doing a registration system where it takes user data (default) and an image that is selected but inside the execution I get this error:

> Fatal error: Param count and argument count do not match. in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ rnip \ durango \ insert \ fingerprints.php on line 54

I tried in appserver but, it has not worked

```
 if (empty($huella0)) {
  //echo "El campo huella0 está vacío <br>"; 
}else{

    $msquerys=sqlsrv_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO imagenes 
    (ID_ALTERNA, 
     ESTADO_EMISOR, 
     EMISOR,
     IMAKEY, 
     DESIMA, 
     TIPO, 
     FOLIO, 
     GRUPO, 
     IMAGEN) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");
$msresultss=sqlsrv_execute($msquerys, array(
    $id_alterna, 
    $estado_emisor, 
    $emisor, 
    $imakey, 
    $desima, 
    $tipo , 
    $folio, 
    $grupo0, 
    $huella0))

or die('<div align="center"><p align="center"><strong># Imposible guardar la huella 0 información contacte a soporte técnico #</strong></p> </div>  ');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the parameters' array to the prepare statement?

Comment: Has probado publicar en https://es.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: 194/5000
with respect to the matrix of the parameters if you mean to leave the values that the variable of each field will receive if it has been done as for example:

$ sql = insert into (NAME) values ($ name);

Comment: @luis cazares I get this Array ([0] => Array ([0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -40 [code] => -40 [2] => An error occurred translating string for input param 9 to UCS-2: No hay ninguna asignacin en la pgina de cdigos de múltiples bytes de destino para el carácter Unicode. [message] => An error occurred translating string for input param 9 to UCS- 2: No hay ninguna asignacin en la pgina de cdigos de múltiples bytes de destino para el carácter Unicode.))

Comment: You're using unicode to insert into a non-unicode column. Either you change the column or you specify the codepage 1252 to convert into a non-unicode string before inserting (I don't know how to do that in php).